# Why does jQuery Extend Deep Copy not recursively copy an object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, extend, javascript-objects, deep-copy

I've searched everywhere and found similar questions with answers that didn't really address my issue so I apologize if this seems like a repeat, but it appears from my experimenting that jQuery's deep copy function doesn't actually work as it's described (or maybe I'm misreading its description).

Here's an example demonstrating the problem I'm having:
http://jsfiddle.net/wcYsH/

Or this for download:
https://github.com/kevroy314/jQuery-Extend-Test

Why does the data in the previous copy get changed when the deep copy is manipulated?

Comment: Do you want to use `jQuery`'s `.clone` instead?

Comment: There was a thread about this on the jQuery forums recently. I think your usecase falls outside of the purpose of the $.extend method. https://forum.jquery.com/topic/deep-copies-using-extend-on-object-instances

Comment: Here's a related bug ticket http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/10014

Comment: So glad I'm not going crazy! `jQuery` `.clone` was what I investigated initially, but I saw [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-clone-a-javascript-object) answer to a similar question and decided I'd try it first.

Comment: Update: It looks like .clone will not clone my type of object. Only DOM objects. I think the best solution right now is to write a clone function for each of my objects and let them handle self-replication themselves.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For one, you aren't creating normal objects.

I'm looking at the source code for jQuery 1.7.2 for extend.

https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/core.js

And I'm noticing the line:

```
if ( deep && copy && ( jQuery.isPlainObject(copy) || (copyIsArray = jQuery.isArray(copy))
```

has to evaluate to `true` to do deep copying. copy is just part of the current object being copied.

But you aren't creating "plain" objects.  You are creating objects generated by invoking a constructor with the new operator.

Now, in isPlainObject, it seems these lines have to be evaluated.  (where hasOwn is `hasOwn = Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty`

```
    try {
        // Not own constructor property must be Object
        if ( obj.constructor &&
            !hasOwn.call(obj, "constructor") &&
            !hasOwn.call(obj.constructor.prototype, "isPrototypeOf") ) {
            return false;
        }
    } catch ( e ) {
        // IE8,9 Will throw exceptions on certain host objects #9897
        return false;
    }
```

And there's where it concludes it's not a "plainObject".

This makes sense when you consider objects with a constructor *probably ought to be created via that constructor* or at least use some sort of "clone" method as you'd see in other languages/frameworks.

Comment: Thank you! That's the explanation I was looking for. I've gone ahead and written a .clone function for each object I've created. Unfortunately, the hacky way I was using .extend apparently was copying the objects just deep enough that my application worked, but shallow enough as  to not waste memory, so now my implementation is a horrible memory hog! Back to the drawing board!